# Office won't start correctly under windows 10 preview

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013, windows-10-preview

So a few days ago, I was trying to open Word 2013 (part of 365 plan) to do some family work and this would constantly pop up in my face!

[image: Word Error]

Then when I tried to open Excel, this would always pop up when I tried to open a new / existing sheet.

[image: Excel Error]

- I re-installed and NOTHING happened.
- Google has no info.
- I have over 300 GB of storage space.
- I have 7 GB of RAM.

What is going on?

I am running Windows Tech Preview (Windows 10) which runs software like Windows 8.1.

Comment: Go into *Word Options* and check, eg, the auto-backup file location setting in the *Save* tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on Windows 10 Preview. I also reinstalled Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've had a corruption in the Office configuration files - this is the sort of things that happens with betas (Tech previews).

Here's a good description of 'Environment Variables' that should help. You're looking for the environment variable called 'temp'.

[TEMP vs TMP in Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/709953/temp-vs-tmp-in-environment-variables)

Basically, what looks like has gone wrong is that the Office programs are trying to save files & data to a place that doesn't exist (or might be read only, or something similar). The location is stored in the environment variable called 'temp', so you should check that this is a real location, and if it isn't, then change it.  This should help:

http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

Comment: My **computer** runs Windows Tech Preview.

Comment: If you're not sure if how to adjust environment variables which is a perfectly valid possible solution, you probably shouldn't be running the tech preview...

Comment: Sadly, no joy. =(

Comment: There was a patch that if installed would break office 2013 this patch was then fixed at some point but if you released the original version the justrepair the office installtion

Comment: Already repaired earlier

Comment: So, what location is "temp" set to?